# Changing option menu button image programmatically - ResourcesNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I have a microphone button in my options menu. When I click it, I want it to display an alternate image( red microphone ).

But it's not working. Fails with ResourcesNotFoundException. The images(png's) are definitely in the appropriate res folders.

Here's my code: 
In activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.ic_action_microphone :
      MenuItem rec = m_menu.findItem(R.id.ic_action_microphone);
      if (m_start) {                
        rec.setIcon(R.id.ic_action_microphone_active);
        startRecording();
      } else {
        rec.setIcon(R.id.ic_action_microphone);
        stopRecording();
      }
      return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

In xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/ic_action_microphone"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_microphone"
      android:title="@string/action_microphone"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/ic_action_microphone_active"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_microphone_active"
      android:title="@string/action_microphone"/>  
 </menu>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead: Set icon by providing images from the drawable resource folders.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.ic_action_microphone :
         MenuItem rec = m_menu.findItem(R.id.ic_action_microphone);
         if (m_start) {                
            rec.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_microphone_active);
            startRecording();
         } else {
            rec.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_microphone);
            stopRecording();
         }
         return true;
      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

You probably want to set resource from drawable and not ids. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Great. I am glad it did.

Comment: The OP should answer this because  I went off his question;